# Google App Engine The url "/" does not match any handlers error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to run a program from https://github.com/rutherford/nltk-gae because I want to use NLTK in Google App Engine. I copied necessary files to the folder and when I run I get this error **"The url "/" does not match any handlers."** I think something wrong in my app.yaml configuration. Please help me to find out the problem, thanks.

my python code
[image]

app.yaml

[image]

---

I changed it but still not working

```
application: nltkforappengine
version: 0-1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.gif
  upload: favicon.gif

- url: /nltk.*
  script: nltker.application
- url: /.*
  script: nltker.application


libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

Comment: You don't have any handler for handling '/' what you do have is a handler for '/nltk' so that should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a handler for '/nltk' (thats what line 12-13 of `app.yaml` do, supported by the `WSGIApplication` configuration at the bottom of `nltker.py`).

There is no handler specified for '/'.

From a quick glance at the code, it looks like the author's intent is that you use `/nltk` as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if I create a new handler for '/', what changes I should make in app.yaml?

Comment: Copy paste the same handler for the url '/nltk.*' instead just change url to /.* and place it under /nltk

Comment: I think you'll have a much easier time of this if you take a bit of time to walk through the getting started tutorial, or at least the first half of it. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/

Answer (score 1):

you need to type the full url to get it to work ie

```
127.0.0.1:8080/ntlk
```

otherwise u get an error

Comment: You also need to change it back in the app.yaml

Comment: thanks very much its working now but importing NLTK is still a problem